# error in mysql (correspond to your mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I am creating a form to be filled and send it to my database.
this is the form :

```
<form method="post" name="event" action="insertLivepro.php">
                    <ul>
                    <li> Khutbah/Lecture Title <input name="KhutbahLive" type="text" ><br></li>
                    <li>Date <input name="DateLive" type="date"> <br></li>
                    <li>Time <input name="TimeLive" type="time"> <br></li>
                    <li>Khutbah/Lecture By <input name="KhatibLive" type="text"><br></li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitAct" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset">
                </form>
```

and this is insertLivepro.php:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO livepro (KhutbahLive, DateLive, TimeLive, KhatibLive)
VALUES('$_POST[KhutbahLive]','$_POST[DateLive]','$_POST[TimeLive]','$_POST[KhatibLive]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

echo '<script> alert ("done!") </script>';
include_once("admin.php");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and this is my database:

[image: this is the livepro table]

so I got this error when I fillup the form and submit:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Day','2014-06-13','15:30','Ustaz. Don ')' at line 2

thanx

Comment: Please add the whole SQL query.

Comment: Almost certainly a case of not escaping values.... so start learning how to use prepared statements/bind variables with MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Paste the entire query

Comment: is it happen because I had same form and database table? but its in different names ??

Comment: Look [here](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html) how to insert Date values in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are inserting an `apostrophe` through the textbox. your problem can be solved in two ways.

1: Try using two apostrophes for every apostrophe.

2: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` in your query . Like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO livepro (KhutbahLive, DateLive, TimeLive, KhatibLive)
VALUES('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[KhutbahLive])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[DateLive])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[TimeLive])','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[KhatibLive])')";
```

Comment: I didnt get the 1st option and I'd tried the 2nd option but yet having the same error

Comment: that means if you are inserting father's day then insert father''s day instead.